# How to find record in dictionary based on value formthis record?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find a record on which `symbol` has value "ETHUSDT", because I'm not sure if index (which is 12 at the moment) will not change in the future.

```
{
    "symbol": "ETHUSDT",
    "priceChange": "-4.85000000",
    "priceChangePercent": "-2.036",
    "weightedAvgPrice": "233.63390151",
    "prevClosePrice": "238.26000000",
    "lastPrice": "233.41000000",
    "lastQty": "4.43014000",
    "bidPrice": "233.40000000",
    "bidQty": "9.49871000",
    "askPrice": "233.41000000",
    "askQty": "34.45162000",
    "openPrice": "238.26000000",
    "highPrice": "239.39000000",
    "lowPrice": "230.02000000",
    "volume": "587784.85506000",
    "quoteVolume": "137326468.93381370",
    "openTime": 1594858810263,
    "closeTime": 1594945210263,
    "firstId": 160868799,
    "lastId": 161091215,
    "count": 222417
},
```

```
import requests

#BINANCE EXCHANGE TICKER API

binance = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr"
responce = requests.get(binance)
print(responce.json() [12])
```

Answer (score 0):

the reponse json is actually a list of dictionaries, where symbol is a key in those dictionaries

if you want to access data the want you say..you can build an index and use it to search the list:

```
json = responce.json()
index = {x['symbol']:i for i,x in enumerate(json)}
print(json[index['ETHUSDT']])
```

output:

```
{'askPrice': '233.39000000',
 'askQty': '2.27670000',
 'bidPrice': '233.38000000',
 'bidQty': '0.21429000',
 'closeTime': 1594937569840,
 'count': 218886,
 'firstId': 160857634,
 'highPrice': '239.39000000',
 'lastId': 161076519,
 'lastPrice': '233.39000000',
 'lastQty': '51.95484000',
 'lowPrice': '230.02000000',
 'openPrice': '238.71000000',
 'openTime': 1594851169840,
 'prevClosePrice': '238.71000000',
 'priceChange': '-5.32000000',
 'priceChangePercent': '-2.229',
 'quoteVolume': '134687953.46775490',
 'symbol': 'ETHUSDT',
 'volume': '576020.98591000',
 'weightedAvgPrice': '233.82473341'}
```

or just make a dict of dicts:

```
out = {x['symbol']:x for x in json}
out['ETHUSDT']
```

same output